# Error when printing to printer shared from CUPS server

Tags: linux, printer, samba, cups

Setup:

- Raspberry Pi running Raspbian/CUPS/Samba
- 2 Epson LX300+ dot matrix printers connected via USB
- Windows XP clients printing via LPT ports

The setup was working fine for many months, however it is now not possible to print to one of the printers (the other still works fine.)

When attempting to print using ipconfig > LPT2 for example, the following error is returned:

> Unable to complete the requested operation because of either a
>   catastrophic media failure or a data structure corruption on the disk.

The other printer works without issue.

It is also possible to print a test page from the CUPS panel so it looks like the issue is somewhere in CUPS/Samba, however I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any advice is appreciated.

**Update**

After simply adding the printer under a different name it is now working fine, so just a policy update and all stations will be back up and running.

When I get time I'll grep through for any name specific config and find out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the printer under a different name it is now working fine, so there is a fault linked to the old printer name in the system.